# Elasticsearch service does not run at statup on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: elasticsearch, service, startup, ubuntu-16.04

I installed elasticsearch on Ubuntu 16.04.

When I enter `sudo service elasticsearch start`, everything works.

But the service is not running on startup. Before starting it manually, `sudo service elasticsearch status` gives me:

```
elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; disabled; vend
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
```

I tried to add it to startup with:
`sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch defaults` and `sudo update-rc.d elasticsearch enable`, but this changes nothing.

What could be the problem, and how can I debug this?

Comment: Did you checked the logs?

Comment: What logs do I have to check? Where are service startup errors logged?

Comment: Elasticsearch logs, syslogs vs http://www.howtogeek.com/117878/how-to-view-write-to-system-log-files-on-ubuntu/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Did not find the error. Just reinstalled it with dpkg. Works, and the data and config hasn`t been overwritten.

Answer (score 8):

The answer to your problem is running this:

```
sudo systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
```

Elasticsearch on Ubuntu 16.04 uses `SystemD` not `System V` anymore.

For some reason when (as of 9th Jan 2016) you install ES 5.1 (not sure if other versions are affected) from APT by default this service does not start.